# How can I protect a hard disk being read when drive is inserted into another computer without using encryption?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, sata, disk-encryption, hard-drive-recovery

Besides using an encrypting-filesystem on-disk, what other options are there for password-protecting a hard disk, so that when it is removed from a computer's encasing or laptop its contents cannot be read by reinserting it into another device and mounting the filesystem found on it?

Comment: Encrypting is the only solution.... other solutions involve not storing the data on the disk in the first place (cloud/server storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enable a hard drive password in the BIOS, which are part of the ATA standard.

- [HDD passwords and security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#HDD_passwords_and_security)
- [Hard Disk Passwords Explained: Should You Set One to Secure Your Files?](http://www.howtogeek.com/186881/hard-disk-passwords-explained-should-you-set-one-to-secure-your-files/)

This will be saved into the hard drive's hardware and will prevent using the HDD unless the password is provided.

Since this password is embedded into the drive, moving the drive to another computer would still require the password to be able to use it.

Caveats:

- ATA passwords can potentially be cracked and/or circumvented ([info](https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/ISO/Breaking+ATA+password+security)).
- Unless the drive itself implements [SED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-based_full_disk_encryption) (Self-Encrypting Disk) functionality, no encryption is done, it's just locked with the password.

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware of the fact the SATA had to implement SED. Thanks.

Comment: It does NOT. As @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 said, "UNLESS the drive itself implements SED..."

Comment: Truth is I always wonder how much security is increased by self encryption. As mentioned in "(info)", "It's very important to understand that even though data on an SED is always encrypted, since the drive controller will decrypt data upon request, some mechanism to restrict access from unauthenticated users must be implemented." So if someone found a way to crack/circumvent the ATA password (security feature set), self encryption might not help at all. (Instead, what it provides is merely a fast way to "erase" the data on the drive -- regeneration of the encryption key)

Answer (score -1):

Like Big Chris says - the **only real secure solution is encryption**.

But, if you're dead set against encryption, the next best thing is to lock the hard drive in a box, physically preventing it from being connected to another computer. Or lock up your whole laptop, or lock the room, or house - anything to *stop people from grabbing your hard drive in the first place*.

You'd still need a key or combination to unlock the box/door, and it could be broken into a LOT easier than properly configured encryption could be broken. A hammer & crowbar or hacksaw can break into just about anything, but it should take years (maybe even decades or a lifetime) to break good encryption.